# Login error on wicket (Java-sqlite -Netbeans IDE) on my project

Tags: session, authentication, wicket

I am doing a project on wicket (Java-SQLite-NetBeans IDE). I can't run the login function.

When I push login button it gives the error below:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WebSession cannot be cast to itucs.blg361.g03.Users.UserSession
>        at itucs.blg361.g03.HeaderPanel$LoginForm.onSubmit(**HeaderPanel.java:263**)

```
public static final class LoginForm extends Form {        
...

261 @Override

262 public final void onSubmit() {

263 **UserSession session = (UserSession) getSession();**

...}
```

NOTE : As I understand It can't create session. Why It can be? Please Help:)

```
public class UserSession extends WebSession {

 private String userName;
    private int userGroup;
    private User user;



protected UserSession(Request request) {
        super(request);
         //user = new User();
         //userName = user.getName();
         //userGroup = user.getGroup_id();
    }

    public final  boolean LogIn( String username, String password) {
        if (userName == null) {
            Application app = (Application) this.getApplication();
            UserCollection usrCollection = app.getUserCollection();
            if (usrCollection.UserEntry(username,password)) {
                this.user = usrCollection.getUser(username);
                this.userName=user.getName();
                this.userGroup=user.getGroup_id();
            }
        }

        return userName != null;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }
    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
       this.userName =user.getName();
        this.userGroup=user.getGroup_id();
    }

    public String getUserName(){
        return userName;
    }

    public int getuserGroup() {
        return userGroup;
    }

    public boolean isSignedIn() {
        return userName != null;
    }

    public void SignOut(){
       userName = null;
        user=null;
        userGroup=0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you return your own WebSession implementation in the Application class?

Comment: I learned this now, i didnt know it before, thanks too much again. It worked now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting my comment in an answer so the question can be closed:

You need to override the [Application.newSession()](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/Application.html#newSession%28org.apache.wicket.request.Request,%20org.apache.wicket.request.Response%29) member to return your own implementation of the Session.

Hope that helps.

PS: Looking through your other questions i noticed that you have some of them answered by others, but you did not accept those answers. Marking them answered will increase the changes that further questions of you will get answers.